How do you balance enemy unit composition when building deliberately challenging scenes?
I have been running a Lancer game 1-2 times a month for almost a year now and feel comfortable with the in-the-moment mechanics of the system, but sometimes find myself struggling when it comes to designing scenes, specifically when choosing which NPC classes to deploy.
The GM advice in the core rulebook lays out various sitreps, but these only give guidelines on map layout and number of enemy NPCs. There is also a small section about difficulty that mostly boils down to adding more units, and reminding the GM that the correct level of difficulty depends on your own game. This is all good advice, and I know from knowing my players that they are interested in the tactical combat aspect of the game and appreciate challenging encounters.
What I find myself struggling with when building encounters that are deliberately more challenging is how much to include units or synergies that specifically counter or mitigate the player's own synergies and strengths. Of course, it's not fun if every encounter is an elite team built to hard-counter you, but it can also get boring if the enemy is always weak to the same combo.
In addition to the simple fun aspect, it's not a challenging combat if the enemy party is not effective in combat. I find myself wondering how practical it is to depend on an interaction between multiple NPC abilities when dealing with some of the potential synergies between players.
While some of this is always going have to come down to trial and error, are there some useful guidelines for balancing these aspects?

It's okay for the GM to win.
You're not actually doing anything permanent by exploding player mechs and downing their pilots. By default player pilots can recover from Down And Out status, and player mechs can be reprinted because licensing is inherent to the pilot. (If you've set up special circumstances that say otherwise, maybe update your question?)
Even if your side "confirms kills" - dealing damage to a pilot when they're in Down And Out status - this is a setting where a sufficiently motivated faction can just have a clone backup of a pilot ready to go.
Your players don't have the best time they could as a result? Oh well! The same thing could happen if they got a few bad dierolls at the wrong time. And maybe it feels worse because, unlike the dice, OpFor composition is your fault? But also, unlike the dice, you can stop yourself from doing the same thing again.
Still, it can hit better and it can hit worse. Here are some things to keep in mind.
Tips For Experimenting With New OpFor Compositions

Budget. Community consensus is that a fair fight is 1.5x - 2x your player count in total structure (including reinforcements) and 1.5x your player count in total actions per turn (initial). Elites and ultras use up more of that. Count one full grunt squad as 1 structure and 1 activation. Try not to have more than half your total be striker or artillery-role NPCs; glass cannons are better for you than they are for the PCs because you have more to lose.
Complexity. Try not to have more than 4 or 5 different types of units, more than one optional system per unit type, or more than one unit type that relies on reactions. If you know for certain you can keep track of more triggers and choices than that when you're running the game, go for it, but this is a good starting limit.
Simulation. If you're not using COMP/CON or some other tracker, consider starting? Having your players' mechs in front of you will help you keep their aggregate and personal strengths and weaknesses in mind when picking NPCs to go against them.
Trial. If you're worried about overpowering your players, if you can help it don't wait until it's time for the final boss fight to see if the composition does it. Consider running it out in a sitrep where it's more okay for the players to take losses, like a recon or extraction op, or a "cards stacked against you" op like gauntlet or holdout just before they're due for a full repair.
Throttle. Everybody can see what you have deployed, but only you know what your reinforcements are. If you're worried about a combo, keep some more vanilla reinforcements on hand too; what kind and how quickly your deploy your reinforcements can greatly affect the flow of a battle.


I use compcon to put together the NPCs and my players use it as their primary source for character sheets, but we use Roll20 to actually run the game (I definitely don't think it's the best tool for Lancer but I already pay for pro for other games and haven't wanted to invest in a second VTT quite yet). I'll have to check out the other GM tools available there though, it might be that I'm just ignoring some useful features.

I do appreciate the reminder that I'm allowed to win an encounter or at least wreck some mechs in the process of losing, I definitely feel like I've pulled punches before and it probably was a mistake to do that.

@Sofistication Your players should at least be able to export their current COMP/CON entries so you can bring them up into your version.
